# Best programming way to implement Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mincemeat

We have a problem, which is an ideal case for applying MapReduce programming technique. The initial code for this is written in Python. Now we have the following options:

1. Use Hadoop and Java to implement the MapReduce part.
2. Use mincemeat and Python to implement the MapReduce part.
3. Use Hadoop and Python ([Hadoop MapReduce Program in Python](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/)) to implement the MapReduce part.

I'm not very sure which will be the best option. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Some people are even doubting Hadoop and they are going to suggest Apache Spark. Not really a SO question.

Comment: Since your initial code is in python and it doesn't make much of a difference whether writing MR in python or Java, (3) should be the best option to pursue for your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your initial code is in python and it doesn't make much of a difference whether writing MR in python or Java, (3) should be the best option to pursue for your scenario. You might also like to explore libraries like https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob which make it easier to write MR jobs in python.

Comment: Thanks !!
Also after going through http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/  mrjob seems to be the best option